# How do I locate the dlls that contain .NET

Tags: .net

I believe that I need to reference the following namespace

```
Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security
```

How can I determine which dll references these namespaces so I can set a reference to them? If I search the entire framework 4 in the object browser, I don't see it, but then, I probably need a reference to the dll for it to show up

When I look up the MS documentation, I see no mention.

Documentation on [Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services2.security.aspx)

What I have done in the opast is set a reference to every Microsoft dll I can find then search the object browser to determine which dll it is in. Then, remove the unused dlls. There has to be a better way. How does everyone else locate the dll that defines a namespace and classes that are needed?

When I open the Add Reference dialog and look for Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security, I don't see it.

[image]

Comment: That probably means you don't have it. Anyway, the standard assemblies are in `C:\Windows\assembly`, which is a special folder that interacts with the GAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install .NET Framework 1.1 and Web Service Enhancements 2.0 or you won't be able to find this at all. So will your users. This might be a hassle.

Are you really, really, really sure you want to be using an addon pack for .NET 1.1 in the year 2011?

Comment: I was looking at a code sample that someone provided me that had a C# "Using reference" to this dll. It sound slike there should be a .BNET 4 way of doing this instead.

Comment: There most assuredly is a more modern way of doing the things contained within that addon. (Well, see Dan Rigby's comment as well, since apparently WSE can be useful in some edge cases) So, you should therefore open a new question asking how to perform the task you're attempting :)

Answer (score 2):

That assembly is part of the Web Services Enhancements (WSE) for .NET library.

WSE is a fairly old technology with several versions that has mostly been replaced by [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) as of .NET 3.0 and above.

WSE versions 1.0 & 2.0 require the 8 year old .NET 1.1 to be installed in order to use the library while WSE 3.0 requires .NET 2.0 to be installed.

WSE is still used occasionally to interop with SOAP services that sometimes don't play well with WCF's implementation of SOAP (ie, Java).

The different WSE versions can be downloaded from the following links:

[WSE 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14089)

[WSE 2.0 SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23689)

[WSE 1.0 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4065)